# Slow intent broadcast delivery on Android 14

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, service, android-14

I have 2 services in my app that sometimes communicate with each other via broadcast intents. The time between an intent being sent and getting delivered on Android 13 is 1-2ms (tested on a Pixel 4XL). The time on Android 14 is ~500ms (tested on a Pixel 6 Pro)!

The slow intent delivery is causing a lag in my app that wasn't there before. I know about the context-registered broadcasts being queued while apps are cached as of Android 14, but this is between an actively running foreground service and an Accessibility service. Are all intents slowed down on Android 14?

Does anyone know what may be causing this performance issue?

**EDIT:** Upon further testing, it looks like intents are delayed 500ms when there is no activity in the foreground. There is no delay while there IS an activity in the foreground. The delay appears as soon as you leave the app, even without killing it.

**So it appears that intents are slowed down even between foreground services, if there is no activity in the foreground.** Is this [documented](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/summary)?

Is there anything I can do to prevent this? I'm using a dynamically registered receiver:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverInternal, intentFilter, RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);
    } else {
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverInternal, intentFilter);
    }
```

Setting it to exported does not make a difference.

Comment: "I have 2 services in my app that sometimes communicate with each other via broadcast intents" -- why? Are they in separate processes?

Comment: Yes, they are in separate processes. Please see my latest edit @CommonsWare

Comment: Is the UI in the same process as the foreground service? If not, does the UI have a bound connection to the foreground service? If so, your experience would line up with foreground UI being sufficient to avoid the delay, but a foreground service alone is insufficient. "Is there anything I can do to prevent this?" -- try a manifest-registered receiver. If this is a side-effect of the new queuing system, the docs say manifest-registered receivers are ignored.

Comment: The UI is also in its own process and bound to one of the services. Yes, having UI in the foreground eliminates the delay, but these services work in the background. I need them to work fast regardless of if my UI is showing. The documentation says services may be placed into the cached state after running for over 30 minutes. Does this include foreground services? Can we find the Android code that applies this delay? It seems to always be almost exactly 500ms. I will try manifest receivers, and update here.

Comment: @CommonsWare you were correct, there is no added delay if the intent is delivered to a manfiest-registered receiver, although it is a bit slower (~10ms instead of 1-3ms). How do I use this static receiver (now in its own class) in my service which was supposed to receive the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like sendOrderedBroadcast() is not affected by this background delay applied to sendBroadcast() in Android 14, so I will be using that instead.

Answer (score 1):

> you were correct, there is no added delay if the intent is delivered to a manfiest-registered receiver, although it is a bit slower (~10ms instead of 1-3ms)

That suggests that your ~500ms slowdown was due to the new queuing system seen on Android 14. It's possible they might improve that someday, but I wouldn't count on it.

> How do I use this static receiver (now in its own class) in my service which was supposed to receive the message?

At a high level, you would use it the same way as you did your dynamic receiver. They receive broadcasts and act upon them.

Ideally, your service has very little actual business logic. While book examples () will tend to have services do real work, that's to keep the examples simple. A service should be focused purely on setting itself up (e.g., displaying the foreground notification) and handling whatever lower-level communication it needs to (e.g., implementing the API surface for accessibility). *Everything* else should reside elsewhere, such as in an object that gets injected into the service. That way, the "elsewhere" can be tested in isolation.

If you have that architecture, having the static receiver also get the "elsewhere" injected and calling methods on it is not significantly different than having the dynamic receiver call methods on the one injected into the service itself. The receiver, like the service, should do next to nothing on its own, other than pass relevant information to the "elsewhere", which does the real work.

If you want to try to get rid of the ~10ms latency, you could experiment with a bound connection between the services, getting rid of the broadcast entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, this would require a lot of re-structuring as my services do the work within them. Thankfully I found another workaround! I will put it into its own answer. My bigger concern here is how this was not documented by Google. I didn't realize an app running a foreground service, and especially an Accessibility service, is considered "cached" immediately upon the UI going into the background. Or maybe a real cached service would receive the intents with a much longer delay and this 500ms is more like a bug. Should I create a bug report?

Comment: @Flyview: "Should I create a bug report?" -- if you're looking for them to update docs, I would not bother. I've filed many, many documentation bug reports over the years, and they mostly get ignored. If you're looking for them to update the *implementation*, I suppose you could try. However, "be careful what you wish for", insofar as they might nerf your workaround.

Comment: Yea, I've filed a few bug reports over the years and nothing has been fixed. They really need a better/bigger team to fix bugs or else they will accumulate and wreak havoc.